# Why isn't my windows 7 pc opening websites

Tags: windows-7

I use a windows 7 pc and have never installed anything that could have possibly been a virus. The problem is that when I open a google tab it looks like it is working, but when I type in any website it shows me a screen saying "This site can't be reached" and below it in small text is "some website is currently unreachable". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome as the browser? and can you provide a screenshot of the browser giving the error message?

Comment: No browsers are working. It says I am connected to wifi, and have also tried different ones and it doesn't work. I can't take the screenshot and post it because I literally can't open anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a DNS server issue. Try the following:

---

**Try flushing your DNS:**

Open Command Prompt as administrator and type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then execute the following commands afterwards, one after another:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

```
netsh winsock reset
```

---

**If that doesn't work, try changing your DNS:**

Instructions on doing this can be found here: https://www.techbout.com/change-dns-server-in-windows-10-22743/

Here are some good DNS servers to try: https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062